# Reading block of memory into array?

Tags: c#

I am using the method below to read bytes in memory.  I want to read values in memory addresses which are very near each other.  Previously I have been making individual calls for each byte in memory and adding the result to an array using a for loop.  This became really inefficient, so instead I want to adapt the below code to read a large block of memory and then try to do an itteration through the array to pull out the bytes I want.  I have spent a bit of time trying to work it out, but really struggling.  FYI, this method reads a pointer, and then if that value is a pointer, it reads that pointer, and so forth until it gets to the static address then reads the byte value at that address.

```
[DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint = "ReadProcessMemory")]
private static extern byte ReadProcessMemoryByte(int Handle, int Address, ref byte Value, int Size, ref int BytesRead);


public static byte ReadPointerByte(string EXENAME, int Pointer, int[] Offset)
{
    byte Value = 0;
    checked
    {
        try
        {
            Process[] Proc = Process.GetProcessesByName(EXENAME);
            if (Proc.Length != 0)
            {
                int Bytes = 0;
                int Handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, Proc[0].Id);
                if (Handle != 0)
                {
                    foreach (int i in Offset)
                    {
                        ReadProcessMemoryInteger((int)Handle, Pointer, ref Pointer, 4, ref Bytes);
                        Pointer += i;
                    }
                    ReadProcessMemoryByte((int)Handle, Pointer, ref Value, 2, ref Bytes);
                    CloseHandle(Handle);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
    return Value;
}
```

What I have so far:

```
 private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] valuesSeperated[200];
        List<byte> PreArray = new List<byte>();
        Process[] test = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyProcess"); //Get process handle 
        int baseAddress = test[0].MainModule.BaseAddress.ToInt32(); //Get base address
        byte ReadX  = MyClass.ReadPointerByte("MyProcess", BaseAddress, new int[] { 0xc, 0x0, 0x2 }); //call memory reading function (including memory offsets)
        PreArray.Add(ReadX);
                byte[] PreArrayToInt = PreArray.ToArray();
                int[] MYConvertedBytes = PreArray ToInt.Select(x => (int)x).ToArray();
                foreach (int i in MYConvertedBytes)
{
valuesSeperated // (don't really know what to do here, if the read was successful I would have a long number at [0], so now need to seperate these as if I had read each one in memory one at a time. 
}

string TestString = MYConvertedBytes[0].ToString();
                label1.Text = TestString;
    }
```

So to summarize: I don't know how to read a larger block of memory (say 200 addresses at once) using the above method.  I don't know how best to extract the values from the resulting array to form a new array that has the bytes now separated.  Please ask if anything is unclear, I am quite new and really want to learn so any hints/help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Would it perhaps not be easier just to use actual pointers and unsafe arrays to get a contiguous memory block? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/patricksmacchia/csharp2unsafecode02162006063859am/csharp2unsafecode.aspx

Comment: @ Mark, hi I am going to read that link now

Comment: @ Mark, hmm not sure I know enough to get much from that at this point, thanks anyway.

Comment: Why not just have the two programs pass the data back and forth  via a shared memory block? That'll be much faster than `ReadProcessMemory` and also be more secure.

Comment: Raymond, can you elaborate on this please? I have never heard of this concept before. The memory space I am reading is not a program I have source code for btw so it isn't much under my control if you know what I mean. Baring in mind I am a novice also.

Comment: Here you go: [File Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Your interop signature looks completely wrong to me.

The c signature is:

```
BOOL WINAPI ReadProcessMemory(
  __in   HANDLE hProcess,
  __in   LPCVOID lpBaseAddress,
  __out  LPVOID lpBuffer,
  __in   SIZE_T nSize,
  __out  SIZE_T *lpNumberOfBytesRead
);
```

It should be something like:

```
[DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint = "ReadProcessMemory",SetLastError=true)]
private static extern unsafe bool NativeReadProcessMemory(IntPtr processHandle, IntPtr baseAddress, byte* buffer, IntPtr size, out IntPtr bytesRead);

static unsafe void ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr processHandle, IntPtr baseAddress, byte[] buffer,int start, int size)
{
    fixed(byte* pBuffer=buffer)
    {
        IntPtr bytesRead;
        if(!NativeReadProcessMemory(processHandle, baseAddress, pBuffer+start,(IntPtr)size, out bytesRead))
           throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        if((int)bytesRead!=size)
            throw new Exception("Incomplete read");//User better exception type here
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean instead of this: private static extern byte ReadProcessMemoryByte(int Handle, int Address, ref byte Value, int Size, ref int BytesRead);?

Comment: Ok, so if I were to change the interop signature, how would I use to do what I am trying? make lpBuffer = MyArray? (previously set as [200])