# Make this Readprocessmemory code a lot more efficient

Tags: c#

**Introduction**

Currently I am using someone's class to read bytes in memory (via pointers). The code I have so far works perfectly, I don't really want to change the way the class is setup if possible (because it works), but hopefully some minor tweaks can be made to the class and my code to make it highly efficient.

**What I achieve at the moment:**

- Start off with a pointer address in memory, reads a byte at that address, adds the data to an array, adds 1 to the original address so we can now read the next address (eg original address is 24004, once the byte is stored, increment 1 and next address to read becomes 24005).
- Reads the byte at the next address (24005), adds this to the same array, adds 1 to that address (next to read becomes 24006).
- And so forth for a fixed number of iterations (approximately 10,000).

**The problem:**

Making 10,000 calls to readprocessmemory one after the other causes a system delay of 20 seconds whilst it goes about its business.

**What I hope can be achieved:**

Perform Readprocessmemory once only, specifying 10,000 bytes of data to be read (instead of just a byte at a time for 10,000 iterations), save this to the array in the same format as I had before with individual bytes (I am aware therefore that instead of array {0} (1) (2).. etc.. I will now just have array {0}, so I would imagine I would need an efficient means of splitting this very large number out into 10,000 numbers (in another array)) The data stored at each address are integers. So for 5 addresses: array {12345} becomes {1}{2}{3}{4}{5}. Where 1 2 3 4 or 5 could just as well be 1 200 40 43 or 20, for example.

So ideally, if I could wave my newbie wand, it would look something like this (class below as well as what I have so far):

***Iteration code:***

```
 private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] valuesSeperated[200];
        List<byte> PreArray = new List<byte>();
        Process[] test = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyProcess"); //Get process handle 
        int baseAddress = test[0].MainModule.BaseAddress.ToInt32(); //Get base address
        byte ReadX  = MyClass.ReadPointerByte("MyProcess", BaseAddress, new int[] { 0xc, 0x0, 0x2 }); //call memory reading function (including memory offsets)
        PreArray.Add(ReadX);
                byte[] PreArrayToInt = PreArray.ToArray();
                int[] MYConvertedBytes = PreArray ToInt.Select(x => (int)x).ToArray();
                foreach (int i in MYConvertedBytes)
{
valuesSeperated // (don't really know what to do here, if the read was successful I would have a long number at [0], so now need to separate these as if I had read each one in memory one at a time. 
}

//new array with 10,000 values created.
    }
```

***Class:***

```
[DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint = "ReadProcessMemory")]
private static extern byte ReadProcessMemoryByte(int Handle, int Address, ref byte Value, int Size, ref int BytesRead);

public static byte ReadPointerByte(string EXENAME, int Pointer, int[] Offset)
{
    byte Value = 0;
    checked
    {
        try
        {
            Process[] Proc = Process.GetProcessesByName(EXENAME);
            if (Proc.Length != 0)
            {
                int Bytes = 0;
                int Handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, Proc[0].Id);
                if (Handle != 0)
                {
                    foreach (int i in Offset)
                    {
                        ReadProcessMemoryInteger((int)Handle, Pointer, ref Pointer, 4, ref Bytes);
                        Pointer += i;
                    }
                    ReadProcessMemoryByte((int)Handle, Pointer, ref Value, 2, ref Bytes);
                    CloseHandle(Handle);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
    return Value;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading block of memory into array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259529/reading-block-of-memory-into-array)

Answer (score 3):

Some advices:

- Do not call OpenProcess / CloseHandle inside your "managed wrapper" (ReadPointerByte, or whatever...), you can use the [Process.Handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.handle.aspx) property.
- To avoid possible errors related with page's permissions, you might need to wrap calls to ReadProcessMemory with [VirtualProtectEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (one to 'unprotect', allowing reads, and another to 'restore' the previous protection).

Some code:

```
// from http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.readprocessmemory
[DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint = "ReadProcessMemory")]
private static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr Address, 
    [Out] byte[] Arr, int Size, out int BytesRead);

public static byte[] ReadBytes(IntPtr hnd, IntPtr Pointer, int Length)
{
    byte[] Arr = new byte[Length];
    int Bytes = 0;
    if(!ReadProcessMemory(hnd, Pointer, Arr, Length, out Bytes)){
        // Throw exception ...
    }
    // Check if Bytes == Length ...
    return Arr;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get process handle
    Process[] test = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad++");  

    //Get base address
    IntPtr baseAddress = test[0].MainModule.BaseAddress; 

    int bytesToRead = 16;
    int[] valuesSeparated = new int[bytesToRead / 4];
    byte[] ret = ReadBytes(test[0].Handle, baseAddress, bytesToRead);

    // Interpret ret as you like ...

    // Convert ret to int[]
    valuesSeparated = ....

}
```

[**The iteration process**]

You have two options here:

1. Get a full snapshot of the target process's memory into a byte[], and perform your algorithm in this array
2. You can exec a readprocessmemory for each iteration. I believe this is your best option.

Regardless of targe-process-memory-reading-technique, your algorithm is this (I'm having a real hard time translating your text into an implementation...):

**Input:** BaseAddress of process, Offsets

**Output:** byte[] Ret

**Steps:**

```
1: LastPtr = BaseAddress
2: IdxOffset = 0
3: Offset = Offsets[IdxOffset]
4: LastValue = Memory[LastPtr + Offset]
5: Ret.Add(LastValue)
6: IdxOffset++
7: LastPtr = LastValue // Is this it?????
8: If IdxOffset < Offsets.Length then return else goto 3
```

Comment: Hi. The class I included takes the base pointer and reads its address, then if that is a pointer too read that address, and so on until it arrives at the static address through an iteration function. Can you incorporate that into your code? Also, do I just replace "200" with "10,000" effectively?

Comment: 1) If by base pointer you mean the EBP, and if you wish to dump the stack, you might me interested in this [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3123/Playing-with-the-stack).

Comment: 2) Actually, you need to change the 3rd parameter in the ReadBytes function.

Comment: Hi, for point 1, what I mean is in this line " byte ReadX  = MyClass.ReadPointerByte("MyProcess", BaseAddress, new int[] { 0xc, 0x0, 0x2 })" I provided the offsets from the base address, so it will then iterate through the addresses at this function "foreach (int i in Offset)" and the bytes to read from the last address in the iteration is used. On the second point, can I ask why valuesSeparated array = 16/4? I thought we need bytestoread length? 3. What do you mean by interepret ret as you like? and how to convert ret to int[]?- I think the way I do it in my code is longwinded.

Comment: 1. You can read the offsets individually or you can read them all at once (BaseAddress:0x0 to BaseAddress:0xC is 12 bytes), and then read the locations you need (i think this is better than calling the function 3 separate times)

Comment: 2. valuesSeparated array = 16/4 because int = int32 = 4 bytes. if bytestoread = 12 then valuesSeparated.length = 3, you're right.

Comment: 3. forget about the "Interpret ret as you like ...", i only meant that ret has your bytes. To convert a byte array (4 elements) to an int you can use the [BitConverter.ToInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32.aspx) function.

Comment: Hi, the offset function from the original code is critical. The first offset is from the baseaddress which leads to a pointer holding another pointer. The next offset gets added to that and so on, its not how you think that the offsets are all from the base address.  Secondly, the values I need are held in 1 byte, not 4 bytes, which leads me to beleive that the numbers are whole numbers not integers. In that case, I don't know what this line is doing: int[] MYConvertedBytes = PreArray ToInt.Select(x => (int)x).ToArray(); I know for sure my data at each address is only 1 byte though.

Comment: "int[] MYConvertedBytes = PreArray ToInt.Select(x => (int)x).ToArray()" this looks pointless to me. an array with the bytes 0,0,0,1 will be translated to an array with the integers 0,0,0,1, instead of the integer 1. You don't win anything by translating bytes to ints like that.

Comment: Getting to now what you what to accomplish would help. In the "What I achieve at the moment" section, you point you want to read 10000 contiguous addresses through iteration. You will be better off reading all this memory at once! Then you say you want to read individual bytes, that you say are offsets within the target process, starting in BaseAddress (right?). You can read them one by one, no problem.

Comment: The offset iteration arrives at the base of a datastructure. I still want to read 10,000 bytes at once, starting from the base of this structure. Previously I read 1 byte starting at the last pointer address + last offset, then saved into array, then the next byte to the right, then the next, etc, etc. Each byte holds value 0-255. So {0,34,157,23} could be an array with 4 iterations for example. Instead, I want read these 4 bytes at once with one readprocessmemory of 4 bytes (for example) and seperate out the values into an array- Instead of doing readprocessmemory 4 times.

Comment: To clarify the offset iteration process. Image base address is 1000, offsets are {1, 2, 3}. Base address + 1 = 1001. Address 1001 is a pointer which points to 2003. so now 2003 + 2 (second offset) = 2005 which again is another pointer pointing to 5335. 5335 + 3 (last offset) = 5338 which is the last pointer in the series giving the value at the last address of interest. The value is a number (1 byte long). So when I say I want to read 1 byte, I mean I want to retrieve 10,000 bytes of data, seperate them as if I read each number one by one, and store them in an array.

Comment: The offset itteration process need only happen once to arrive at the base of the datastructure. Previously I was using the class to get to the base of the data structure (which works perfectly) then from that point perform 10,000 iterations of readprocessmemory starting for example at the last address in the above xample - 5338, store the byte, then read 5339 store the byte, then read 5340 store the byte, etc.. etc.. until I had a list of 10,000 seperated bytes of data.

Comment: The class I posted above in my code reads 1 byte from the base of the datastructure. So maybe you could adapt it to return the address at the base of the datastructure as opposed to the value and use that for the rest of your code?

Comment: Hi hopefully you respond to those last points, I have awarded the bounty because it expires today.

Comment: Hi I appreciate your efforts, I think I just need to call my readprocessmemory class but change "return value" to "return pointer" (edit the code in the class) so that the correct pointer (last at the end of iterations) is used at the start of your code? Like at the start of your code put: IntPtr Pointer = MyClass.ReadPointerByte("MyProcess", BaseAddress, new int[] { 0xc, 0x0, 0x2 }); And since that class now returns pointer instead of value, it did the iteration for us? Does that work?